# Distinguishable combinations problem

Tags: probability

How many distinguishable combinations of the letters C, O, M, B, and O can you make if you can repeat letters as many times as you want?

Comment: O, OO, OOO, OOOO, OOOOO,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have included $O$ twice in the question I am assuming that you can't repeat the letters in the way it has been in the comment. I think this is what was meant, unless you mean five letter words? But then there is no reason to repeat any letters in the question, the answer is:

$1\cdot3\cdot 4\cdot 5=60$

If you have two letter Os they are indistinguishable so there is only one configuration.

$O,O : 1$

Add another letter, C, it can be positioned at three locations in the combination, so multiply by 3.

$C,O,O : 1\cdot 3$

The next can be positioned at 4 different locations and the next, 5, multiply by 4 then 5.

$C,O,M,O : 1\cdot 3\cdot 4 = 12$

$C,O,M,B,O: 1\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 5=60$

Comment: Wow, I didn't even think about it that way.

Comment: Wait, suppose you could repeat letters in the way it is in the comment. How would I solve that problem?

Comment: There are clearly infinite O, OO, OOO, OOOO, ... is this what you mean?

Comment: No, I mean you can repeat letters, but the combinations can only consist of 5 letters.

Comment: Well how many combinations of numbers can you get in base 10 with 5 digits? 10^5? Having 4 different letters is the same as having base 4 isn't it? how many different numbers can you make with  a maximum of 5 digits in base 4? (0,1,2,3,10,11,12,13,20,...)

Comment: So the answer is $4^5=2^{10}=1024$

Comment: So we just disregard the extra O?

Comment: This is what makes me thing this isn't the case. Five letter words using the letters COMBO using each letter as many times as you like is obviously equivalent to five letter words using COMB as many times as you like!

Answer (score 0):

If it is rearranging $C_1 O_1 M_1 B_1 O_2$, you get $5!$; turn off subscripts ($O_1 O_2$ can be arranged in $2!$ ways, need to divide that out) and you have $\dfrac{5!}{1! \; 2! \; 1! \;1!} = \binom{5}{1 \; 2 \; 1 \; 1}$, a multinomial coefficient, also known as 60.

As an easy exercise, see how many ways you can shuffle the letters in $STACKEXCHANGE$.